Missing points datasets global monitor energy
I want to use the GEM data from Global Monitor Energy and incorporate it into QGIS.
I downloaded the Excel data which I converted to CSV.
Then, I wanted to add the layer thus created with the "text delimited" tool; then I selected "comma" and I entered the values longitude for the X field and latitude for the Y field.
I selected the GMS coordinates and the "EPSG:4326 - WGS84".
Everything is OK, I can see the table.

When I import, only 183 of the 116095 points are visible on the map, whereas in the data table I can see all 116095 points.


What can I do? I've tried everything and I can't find anything...

It is working when I try it.
You have selected "Custom delimiter" in the File Format section when you should select "CSV (comma separated values)".
And your encoding is incorrect, that is why you get the weird symbols at certain characters in the attribute table. I used Windows-1251 when I saved the Excel as csv, you need to select the one you used when saving:

Another option:
Add the Excel sheet to the map:

Create a point layer from the sheet using Geometry by expression:
make_point("Longitude", "Latitude"):

Save it and set the coordinate system:


Unfortunately, when I put in Windows 10 and when I put in csv, it's the same thing...
And when I remove the DMS cordinate button, I have 468 points...

I've added a second solution

Thanks so mushhhhhhh !!!!! It's working !!!
Realy, thank you very mush ;) !!
